# How do I upload a file from Axios to Django?

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, file-upload, axios

I'm switching from Jquery AJAX to react-dropzone & Axios, I'd like to upload a file to my Django server, I have no issue posting a blob url of the image on the server but I want to get it under `request.FILES` but I am getting an empty queryset.

```
request.FILES : <MultiValueDict: {}>  <!--- empty
request.POST  : <QueryDict: {}>       <!--- able to get a blob url
```

---

Here's what my axios configuration looks like :

```
const temporaryURL = URL.createObjectURL(step3.drop[0]);

var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('image', temporaryURL);

axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: SITE_DOMAIN_NAME + '/business-card/collect/',
  data: fd,
  headers: {
    "X-CSRFToken": CSRF_TOKEN, 
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  }
}).then(function (response) {
  console.log(response)
  URL.revokeObjectURL(temporaryURL);
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error)
});
```

I am receiving the file on a classBasedView on POST request.

How can I upload the file? Where am I wrong?

**Edit**

I also tried "application/form-data", doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem came from the `content-type` as it was using `"application/form-data"` instead of `"multipart/form-data"`.

Comment: how to do this with `axios.post(url, data, config)`?

Comment: @JChao The same as above, replace `url` with your endpoint, `data` with the payload and `config` with the headers.

Comment: I tried that. It seems like Django cannot find the file data once it's passed over. I was wondering if my header was wrong, but setting content-type in `data` doesn't help me. My application is still using angularJS. and we use `ngf-drop` library to deal with drag and drops. When I console.log my `data`, I can see the file there, but after being sent to Django, the file disappears. Do you know what's going on here?

Comment: @JChao `content-type` should be in the headers, not in `data`. What kind of data are you sending `json` or using the `FormData` object?

Comment: I think I need to append all things in my object into FormData object one by one. Still trying it out here. Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0):

I am answering in case, someone comes here by searching on google:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('myFile', file);
formData.append('otherParam', 'myValue');

axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'myUrl',
  data: formData,
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }
}).then(function (response) {
    // on success
}).catch(function (error) {
    // on error 
});
```